# MongoDB - find documents where several properties match condition within the same array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, conditional-statements, element

Document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4dd63bd76f061ef0dbcf28"), 
    "fruits" : [
        {
            "color" : "red", 
            "name" : "strawberry"
        }, 
        {
            "color" : "green", 
            "name" : "cucumber"
        }
    ]
}
```

Matches query:

```
{ "fruits.name": "strawberry", "fruits.color": "green" }
```

Without using aggregation framework, how can I tell MongoDB to only return documents where one of the "fruits" array elements matches both of the conditions in the query (so in my case the result would be no documents)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to match with multiple condition inside an array

```
db.collection.find({
  "fruits": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "name": "strawberry",
      "color": "green"
    }
  }
})
```